# BigQuery Deduplicate rows - No unique columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table which is a result of multiple left join tables.
The results are duplicated because of the left join (cartesian product)

How do I de-duplicate the rows so I only see one record?

```
SELECT T1.Col1,T1.Col2,........
T2.Col1,T2.Col2,........
T3.Col1,T3.Col3,........
T5.Col1,T5.Col2,........
T7.Col1.......


FROM `TABLE1` as T1
LEFT JOIN 
`TABLE`as T2 ON T1.CUSTOMER_CODE = T2.CUSTOMER_CODE
LEFT JOIN 
`TABLE3` as T3 ON (T1.MIAL_CODE) = T3.MIAL_CODE
LEFT JOIN
`TABLE5` as T5
ON T1.WORK_CODE = T5.WORK_CODE
LEFT JOIN 
`TABLE7` as T7
 ON T1.CA_DATE = T7.date


ORDER BY CA_DATE
```

Comment: Can you show us a snapshot of your sql queries ?

Comment: Updated my original question with a snapshot of my query

Comment: wondering if you haven't properly defined your join keys and that's the reason you're getting duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Use DISTINCT:

```
select distinct *
from mytable
```

or create a new table:

```
create or replace table my_new_table
as
select distinct *
from mytable
```

Comment: such approach will lead to scan the whole table to get only distinct values, which might be very expensive in case the table is too large

Comment: yes the resulting table is very large with 40+ columns and millions of records

Comment: If you perform the distinct at the union all query time, there is no additional cost!

Answer (score 1):

I used GROUP BY and it worked fine to get rid of duplicates

```
SELECT T1.Col1,T1.Col2,........
T2.Col1,T2.Col2,........
T3.Col1,T3.Col3,........
T5.Col1,T5.Col2,........
T7.Col1.......


FROM `TABLE1` as T1
LEFT JOIN 
`TABLE`as T2 ON T1.CUSTOMER_CODE = T2.CUSTOMER_CODE
LEFT JOIN 
`TABLE3` as T3 ON (T1.MIAL_CODE) = T3.MIAL_CODE
LEFT JOIN
`TABLE5` as T5
ON T1.WORK_CODE = T5.WORK_CODE
LEFT JOIN 
`TABLE7` as T7
 ON T1.CA_DATE = T7.date

GROUP BY T1.Col1,T1.Col2,........
T2.Col1,T2.Col2,........
T3.Col1,T3.Col3,........
T5.Col1,T5.Col2,........
T7.Col1.......

ORDER BY CA_DATE
```